what is the difference between assets discovered in data scanning and assets obtained in data catalog in Microsoft purview
enter image description here
enter image description here There is a difference between both the assets number in the scan results and the data catalog browse assets. And also, assets discovered were in more number compared to assets ingested.
Can someone me help understand the scan results and how to check the assets in the data catalog? I see the difference in the asset numbers after scanning and the assets reflected in the data catalog page.

Check for any filters or permissions that stopping visibility of assets in the catalog.
